# DML statement cannot operate on Trigger.new or Trigger.old

Tags: apex, soql

I have an afterInsert trigger on Events. When the Script is finished, I would like to delete the event. I keep getting this error message.

> DML statement cannot operate on Trigger.new or Trigger.old

If I cannot do this within Trigger.new, what is the best way to do this? If SOQL is involved, what field am I looking for? event.ID?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You cannot operate on records from the trigger context. You can take those same records and perform `DML` on them if you simply change the reference.

```
List<Event> nonTriggerEvents = new List<Event>();
for (Event triggerEvent : trigger.new)
{
    nonTriggerEvents.add(new Event(Id = triggerEvent.Id));
}
update nonTriggerEvents;
```

However, in this case you can take a simpler approach and call `Database.delete` on a `List<Id>`.

```
List<Id> eventIdsToDelete = new List<Id>();
for (Event newEvent : trigger.new)
{
    eventIdsToDelete.add(newEvent.Id);
}
Database.delete(eventIdsToDelete);
```

Comment: well this is interesting  as [Database.delete documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_database.htm%23apex_System_Database_delete?search_text=datetime%20methods) doesn't have any signature for passing a list of IDs . Way cool

Comment: @crop broken linking system ftw... I do see the signature [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_database.htm) fwiw.

Comment: list<sobject>, yes, not list<ID> _ I didn't realize they were interchangeable in this context until I read this answer. I knew it worked for bind expressions in soql

Comment: @crop No, the signatures are just not all grouped together for some reason, but it's there. Look between `deleteImmediate` and `emptyRecycleBin`.

Comment: i'm an idiot :-)  -- I never read down that far because they got out of alpha order and it was below the fold. I'll file a doc feedback item. The good news is I learned something